# How to update without replacing?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Table `mapping`:

| category | codes |
| --- | --- |
| Bread | 1234, 4453 |
| Tea | 2612, 9234, 2342 |
| Oil | 9394, 4251, 8634, 1235, 6412 |

SQL command trying to update the codes for relevant category:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('category_mapping.db')
c = conn.cursor()

query = f"UPDATE mapping SET codes = 9999 WHERE category = 'Bread'"
c.execute(query)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

But it removes all existing codes and adds 9999 to the category. I also tried:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('category_mapping.db')
c = conn.cursor()

query = f"INSERT INTO mapping (category, codes) VALUES ('Bread', 9999)"
c.execute(query)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Which adds a new category (I get two "Bread" categories). What is the SQL command to update selected category codes, without removing existing codes or adding a new category?

Comment: `SET codes = CONCAT(codes, ', 9999')`

Comment: It would be better to normalize your table so you don't have a comma-delimited list in the first place. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: Never. ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer:

```
code = "9999"
selected_category = "Bread"

query = f"UPDATE mapping SET codes = codes || ',{new_code}' WHERE category = '{selected_category}'"
```

Comment: that looks quite insecure and should be avoided